# Как очистить $_POST, $_GET? Реализация функции отсечения случайной множественной отправки формы.

Tags: forms, post, php, get

1. В заголовке, просьба, ключевики не править: именно по ним ищут эту функцию 99% людей.
2. Часто отвечал, что для контроля отправки надо прописывать айдишник сабмита. И вот что я имел ввиду(решение готовое. Можно брать и юзать):

Проверка:

```
function accidently_submit_check(){
    if(!isset($_POST['submit_id'])){
        //unknown submission attempt or no post data
        return false;
    }
    if(!isset($_SESSION['submit_id'][$_POST['submit_id']])){
        //unknown submission attempt
        return false;
    }
    if($_SESSION['submit_id'][$_POST['submit_id']]){
        //form was already submitted
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

В функции обработки формы, если все нормально:

```
$_SESSION['submit_id'][$_POST['submit_id']] = true;
```

В функции генерации формы:

```
$form['SUBMIT_ID']['value'] = md5(microtime(true).$_SESSION['user']['id']);
$_SESSION['submit_id'][$form['SUBMIT_ID']['value']] = false;

printf('<input type="hidden" name="submit_id" value="%s">',$form['SUBMIT_ID']['value']);
```

Внимание, вопрос: что я упустил?
Все работает, но мало ли.

Comment: А если форма аяксом отправляется? Как получить submit_id для следующей отправки? Т.е. нужно перегенерировать форму после отправки запроса, не совсем удобно. имхо, надо предусмотреть проверку submit_id в куках. впрочем, решается несколько другая задача...

Comment: Если аяксом, можно перегенерировать только submit_id данной аяксовой отправки. :)
Впрочем, над куками подумаю.

Comment: Если аяксом, то в ответе можно просто присылать новый сабмит_ид, а js уже подставит куда нужно.

Comment: @t0di ну да, только форма, "бывает" и так присылает какие-то данные и понадобится дополнительная обертка для submit_id. Например, шлется html какой-то для $("div").html(data), тут придется видимо какой-то json сначала разбирать типа `{"submit_id":asd,"html":"<p>ваша форма обработана</p>"}`. В общем лишние телодвижения.  
А в случае кук можно написать в `$.ajaxSend(document)` подстановку кук делать для любого запроса. Так работают с csrf в django для аякса, например.  
Но говорю, возможно это и не так уж необходимо...

Answer (score 3):

Ну, содержание первой части заголовка вопроса не совсем соответствует самому вопросу.

Очистка $_GET, $_POST производится через header('Location: {referer}');

А то что у вас - немного другое.

Вот ещё вариант:

```
<form onsubmit="document.getElementById('submitButton').disabled = true">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Да, мне тоже подобное решение приходит в голову первым. Да так и делается в большинстве случаев. А всякие SUBMIT_ID более логично применять для защиты от CSRF-атак.

Comment: нет, нет, нет. =) Содержимое первой части не соответствует вообще. Но почему я его оставил - см ниже. Не всегда человек знает точно что ему нужно, иногда он ищет заведомо неверное решение.

По поводу вашего решения: не спасет, если обновить страницу, на которую пришли отправленные данные.

Comment: Очевидно, что нужно использовать 

    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
    // если только обработчик формы находится по тому же адресу.