# Проверка отправки формы

Tags: php

Привет.Какая лучше проверка что форма отправлена?
Припустим у нас есть `<input type="submit" name="submit" >`

что я только не встречал:

1.Cамый популярный вариант  `if (isset($_POST['submit'])`

2.Тоже вариант  `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit']))`

3.Но мне больше всего пригляделся вариант:
 `if ($_POST['photoList']=='submit')`; Это ведь вариант включает по -умолчанию первые 2 проверки.Почему его так массово не используют?

C post вроде более менее понятно,а как же быть с GET -отправкой формы? Ведь любой может прописать в адресной строке нужный параметр

Comment: а если не будет существовать `$_POST['photoList']`? Ошибку же выдаст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

последний вариант не используют, так как в случае, если сабмита не было, будет предупреждение о несуществующем ключе массива.

ИМХО, из простых самый лучший вариант:

```
function form_submitted($form_name=false){
  if(!isset($_POST['submitted'])){ // был ли вообще сабмит
    return false; //неа, завершаем
  }
  if($form_name && $_POST['submitted']!=$form_name){ //если проверяется конкретная форма, была ли отправлена именно она?
    return false;//нет, завершаем
  }
  return true;//все, ок.
}
```

[Более сложный вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/158517/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-_post-_get-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B) - генерить уникальный хэш при каждой генерации формы, чтобы нельзя было отправить несколько раз, например, при обновлении

Поставил ссыль на этот способ

Comment: Как данный прием называется?Он меня очень заинтересовал.Если можно ссылку или дополните пожалуйста свой пост.Мы на первой странице записываем в сессию рандомный hash ,а на новой проверяем существование его?Благодарен.

Comment: обновил...

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, это оптимальный вариант, используйте его
2. Непонятно зачем второе условие, если в submit будет value = ''(пустая строка, здесь подробнее http://php.net/manual/ru/function.empty.php) то ваш код отметит форму как неотправленную, кроме той ошибки оно ничего не дает.
3. Верно, любой может просто прописать в адресную строку все нужные данные и это будет эквивалентно отправке формы. Однако, есть хитрость, можно проверять рефер, с которого пришел пользователь, на то чтобы он был равен текущей странице.

Comment: Про рефферер спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использовать `<input type="hidden" name="f_submitted">` и `if(isset($_POST['f_submitted'])){ ... }`